# php files aren't parsed for virtual hosts

Tags: php, apache

I tried everything possible since last 24 hours :(
I am running new CentOS with apache and PHP/5.3.3 virtual hosts are set up properly, that said all static pages are parsed well (html) even phpadmin works, my sites do not :(

This is one virtual host on my server:

```
<VirtualHost *:80 >

    ServerName www.domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com domain.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com
    DocumentRoot /home/domain/public_html

    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/domains/domain.com.bytes bytes
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/domains/domain.com.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/domains/domain.com.error.log
    <Directory /home/domain/public_html>
        php_admin_flag engine on
        AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

And this is what I get with curl:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 27 Sep 2014 23:10:11 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=dd67d679c04f0b23282b8b6ddcfbd6c131411859411152; expires=Mon,         23-Dec-2019 23:50:00 GMT; path=/; domain=.dirfly.com; HttpOnly
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3
Server: cloudflare-nginx
CF-RAY: 170b5f87b95f0880-IAD

test0
<?
echo "test";
phpinfo();

?>
```

I use the default httpd.conf that comes with CentOs.

It simple doesn't work :(

EDIT: One important thing, if I disable virtual hosts php files are getting parsed normal in default root doc:/var/www/html/index.php

Comment: The curl response shows `Server: cloudflare-nginx` so my bet would be that your server is not running Apache but Nginx instead. Or a combination of both, where Nginx could be the proxy for Apache.

Comment: its just cloudflars system thats infront of my server, nothing then that, I am pretty much straightforward with linux and command prompt and know what runs on my server and what doesn't...but thanks anyway!

Comment: are shortcodes enabled in your php.ini file have you tried <?php instead?

Comment: @mschuett it should work in both cases I think, yes I tried...as I said, without virtual hosts everything works fine.

Comment: whats in your log files right after you try loading a php page that is not parse?

Comment: unfortunately nothing :(

Comment: httpd -t give you anything useful?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62054/discussion-between-mrki-and-mschuett).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you don't have short_open_tag enabled in php.ini, more information here:

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

Or better yet, use <?php instead of <?.

Comment: O man, o man!!! I can't believe that I used <? all the time :( I was focused on all possible configuration files apache, php and didn't notice this simple mistake...mama mia! Thank you for saving my life Ben!

Comment: @mrki are you serious. this was the second thing i asked you (look in the comments) and you assured me it was not the case.